# PHP Include based on URL parameters

Tags: php, php-include

I have a directory that contains 30 php includes with various blocks of html. I am trying to include 5-6 of these files based on the parameters of the url. The files are named like this:

1.php
2.php
3.php
...
30.php

And the URL looks like this:

www.example.com?include=1-4-14-20-29

I need something like this but I know this isn't valid:

```
$include = @$_GET['include'];   // hyphen separated list of file names.

$arr = explode("-", $include);  //explode into an array
foreach ($arr as $filename) {
include $filename."php";
```

}

Result I am trying to get:

```
<php
include '1.php';
include '4.php';
include '14.php';
include '20.php';
include '29.php';
?>
```

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Comment: doesn't this work? For safety and security you should white-list the input, e.g. use a switch with cases '1', '2', ... and resp. include '1.php', '2.php', .. In order not to allow for malicious include requests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would loop through the array, so would take the minimum and the maximum values, like this:

```
<?php
$include = $_GET['include'];   // hyphen separated list of file names.

$arr = explode("-", $include);  //explode into an array

# What's the min and max of the array?
$max = max($arr);
$min = min($arr);

# Just to see what's happening.
echo $max."-".$min;

# Start at the lowest value, and work towards the highest in the array.
for ($i = $min; $i <= $max; $i++) {

# Include the nth php file
include $i.".php";
}

?>
```

**EDIT**

Oh sorry, just seen I've misunderstood your question, you are not looking for ranges, but individual calls. Then this one's for you:

```
<?php
$include = $_GET['include'];   // hyphen separated list of file names.

$arr = explode("-", $include);  //explode into an array
foreach ($arr as $filename) {
include $filename.".php";
}

?>
```